# How do I change a user's password programmatically in a plugin?

Tags: users

I'm new to Craft and (attempting to) create a plugin so that I can import existing users from CSV.

I'm referencing this method:

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/craft-usersservice.html#method-changepassword

In my function, I'm using the following code:

```
$user = craft()->users->getUserById(6);
$user->newPassword('mynewpassword123');
craft()->users->changePassword($user);
craft()->users->saveUser($user);
```

Am I completely misunderstanding what this is supposed to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't need to call changePassword() at all.  Try this:

```
$user = craft()->users->getUserById(6);
$user->newPassword = 'mynewpassword123';
craft()->users->saveUser($user);
```

If it's not updating correctly, then there is likely a validation error somewhere.  You can check that with:

```
$user->getErrors();
```

Which will return an array of properties that failed validation and their error messages.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Craft 3? I can't find anything in the docs