# Update user password

Tags: plugin-development, users, registration, password

I'm trying to update a user password on save via a custom field (on registration via the back-end - the admin needs to specify a password on registering a user). Is this even possible?

Came across this question [How do I change a user's password programmatically in a plugin?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/how-do-i-change-a-users-password-programmatically-in-a-plugin) and tried using the `users.onBeforeSaveUser` event to update the `$user->newPassword` but the user cannot login with the details registered/created.

Any thoughts on above appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `users.onBeforeSaveUser` event to set a user's password as this event happens after the supplied password has been hashed by a private method in the `UsersService`.

Instead, you could use the `users.onSaveUser` event, check if a new user has just been saved and if so add the password to the `userModel` and re-save it. The following is untested, but should do the trick:

```
    craft()->on('users.saveUser', function(Event $event) {

        // Only fire if new user, this should avoid an infinite loop
        if ($event->params['isNewUser']) {

            // retrieve the userModel from the event
            $user = $event->params['user'];

            // set new password
            $user->newPassword = 'My Super Secret Password';

            // save user
            if (craft()->users->saveUser($user))
            {
                // Password successfully saved!
            }
            else
            {
                // Oops, something went wrong!
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks @SteveRowling - that seems to have done the trick. Seem to be going round in circles on this plugin but seem to be nearly there … :D